# how to wait for load newly created elements - puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, domcontentloaded

I want to get the sizes of the product from the adidas.com site using Puppeteer. The sizes are not loaded in the initial loading and the HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="sizes___3Stmf">
<div class="gl-label size___TqqSo" data-testid="size-placeholder"><span class="notranslate placeholder___yXpD2">AAA</span></div>
</div>
```

But after full loading, the elements will change as below and the sizes will be displayed:

```
<div class="sizes___3Stmf gl-vspace" data-auto-id="size-selector">
<button class="gl-label size___TqqSo selected___2CqxQ"><span>36</span></button>
</div>
```

How can I wait for the changed elements to load and then get it?
My code is as follows. I even tried using the waitForSelector() but it didn't work.

```
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
await page.waitForSelector('.sizes___3Stmf button');        
const outputApp = await page.$(".sizes___3Stmf");
const outputHtml = await page.evaluate((el) => el.innerHTML, outputApp);
console.log(outputHtml);
```

I get the following error by running the above code:

```
timeouterror: waiting for selector `.sizes___3stmf button` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded.
```

Comment: It's a good idea to share the actual link because pages are super complex and there are a lot of reasons why a selector wait might fail that go deeper than you might suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on 100% stable element attributes. `sizes___3Stmf` class name doesn't look like one of them.

Try to wait for div with attribute `data-auto-id`:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('div[data-auto-id="size-selector"] button');
```

Comment: TimeoutError: waiting for selector `div[data-auto-id="size-selector"] button` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Comment: I think the full page is not loaded with waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'. Is there a way to wait for the javascript to finish completely? I tried all the ways (load, networkidle2, networkidle0) but it didn't work

Comment: @mohsen Try to save screenshot after page is loaded with `await page.screenshot({path: 'test.png'});`